# Angular js ng-repeat is getting duplicated on using $apply?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I am developing a simple angular and node js app.It uses twitter streaming api.On back end i am using express and socket.io along with "twit" library.

Now here is server.js

```
var express=require('express');
var http=require('http');
var app=express();
var server=http.createServer(app);
var io=require('socket.io').listen(server);
 server.listen(8080);
var Twit=require('twit');

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

app.get('/',function (req,res) {
        console.log("awd");
        res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});

var target=['ferrari'];

var api=new Twit({
    consumer_key:'xxxx',
    consumer_secret:'xxxx',
    access_token:'xxxx',
    access_token_secret:'xxxx'
});

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    var stream=api.stream('statuses/filter',{track:target})
    stream.on('tweet',function(tweet){
        console.log(tweet.text);
        io.emit('stream',tweet);
    });
});
```

Everything is fine at back-end. In front-end side I am using angular JS like this-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="twitter">
<head>
    <title>Twitter</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.7.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   (
    function(){
        var app=angular.module("twitter",[]);
        i=0;
        app.controller("tweets",['$scope',function($scope){
            var socket=io();
             $scope.list=[];

            socket.on('stream',function(tweet){
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    $scope.list.push({name:tweet.text});    
                });


            });
        }]);
    }
    )();
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="tweets">
        <div ng-repeat="t in list">
            <div>{{t.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Best part I am getting the response I want-

```
RT @SonAutosPorno: Ferrari https://t.co/O6VJAVPf6I
Ferrari California T https://t.co/Bfg4SXH9MB
Je roule dans la Ferrari et toi tu marche avec ta jalousie. o/
```

But this DOM doesn`t looks correct.

[image]

Every time a new tweet is broadcasted the $apply is seeing the change but is creating a new ng-repeat element instead of just appending the new info inside the single div.

What is possibly going wrong??

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong; this is how ng-repeat works. It will repeat the element it is declared on.

Comment: @ExplosionPills alright. just asked because it felt wrong. Just one thing more..Can the function inside $apply have multiple other variables as well.Meaning can $apply look for updates in more than one variable like $scope.$apply(function(){$scope.list.push(..);$scope.xyz.push();})

Comment: When you call `$apply` you are forcing a digest cycle / forcing angular to check for changes. This has to be done in asynchronous callbacks such as socket events. As long as you don't trigger another digest cycle, you can do whatever you want in `.$apply`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills thnks .Finally understanding $digest,$apply and $watch.